# Deno import json by using "with" tag beaks prettier

Tags: prettier, deno

```
import data from 'data/pages/home.json' with { type: "json" };
```

Above you can see import which considered to be used from official documentation of Deno https://examples.deno.land/importing-json . And by using it , I see in my `VS Code` , that `with { type: "json" }` this part breaks it by showing this error

[image]

is it possible to fix it somehow ?

Comment: There is an open issue for this in the GitHub repo for Prettier: [prettier/prettier#15699 - Support for import attributes with TypeScript](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/15699)